# Not working flash messages with respond_to in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, redirect, view, controller

I have this simple action (originally generated by scaffold):

```
  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])    
    @item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, :success => 'Post was successfully removed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The page is redirected back, but the alert message is not shown. (snippet for displaying flash messages works well in the whole application, but not here)

What's the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  format.html { redirect_to :back, :flash => {:success => 'Post was successfully removed.' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The flash key is either `:notice` or `:alert`. There is no `:success` key.